# Why does it give the error Can't use 'plotshape' locally?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I don’t understand why the code doesn’t want to display data on the chart, when I looked at the documentation I didn’t find an error in my code
P.S I am using version 5

```
if longCondition
    label.new(x = bar_index, y = high, text = "SHORT", color = color.red, textcolor = color.white, style = label.style_label_up, textalign = text.align_center)
    takeProfitLevelValue = high + (high - low) * takeProfitLevel
    plotshape(series=takeProfitLevelValue, title="Take Profit", location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, style=shape.labelup)
```

I tried to specify through lable.new but still gives an error

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `plotshape()` in a local scope. You should move that to the global scope.

If you want to use the `plotshape()` conditionally, just add your condition to the `series` argument with an `and` operator.

```
if longCondition
    label.new(x = bar_index, y = high, text = "SHORT", color = color.red, textcolor = color.white, style = label.style_label_up, textalign = text.align_center)
    takeProfitLevelValue = high + (high - low) * takeProfitLevel

plotshape(series=longCondition and takeProfitLevelValue, title="Take Profit", location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, style=shape.labelup)
```